Azure Logic App "Execute CSharp Script Code" action saving as empty code section without any csx file
I am trying the new C# script execution on the standard logic app workflow. On workflow designer search, I can see and add the action to the workflow with sample/default code but after saving, and reopening the workflow designer I see no code and an empty text area. Even I don't see any code/script file as "execute_csharp_script_code.csx" in any of the folders.

I even opened the vscode as administrator.
I tried different workflow trigger (http, blobupdate)
I manually created the execute_csharp_script_code.csx file and still not picking the code.

Is there anything that I am missing here to try this new feature?

I missed the important announcement section for this feature.
As of this date, this feature is unavailable to vscode users and is only available on the portal.
As per the announcement:
"
Portal-only support for C# Script Files (.csx This feature is not yet available in VS Code and is aimed at helping users solve management tasks, automate workflows, and handle other C# scenarios directly in Azure Portal without having to configure a local development environment.
"

Yep, you found it. The Advanced Data Operations connector has a C# operation as well that can be built in VS code, might be worth a shot.
